# escaping a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like this... I am trying to insert a class name using a variable `gotValue`.  How do I pass it in jQuery?  I have tried that in if clause, but it did not work.

```
function fullData(gotValue)
{
    alert(gotValue);
    var count = gotvalue.substring(9);
    if($('.'+gotValue+'').is(':checked'))
    {
        alert('working');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of variable `gotValue` you pass through the function?

Comment: @sAc - value like 'redtext'  .. its just a class name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript variables are [case-sensitive](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp); so:

```
gotValue != gotvalue
```

Comment: +1 - He's throwing a syntax error on the `var count` line currently.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that clear what you're trying to do but I think what you want is

```
$('.'+gotValue+":checked")
```